# Improving a clumsy automatic cuboid domain decomposition algorithm

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, factorization, mathematical-lattices

#### Introduction

For my library, I need to split up a cuboid point lattice for assignment to multiple processing elements (PEs).

[image: Example decomposition]

As you can see, no points are shared between the PEs, and certain PEs (here 4-7) get only 2D 'slices'.

The interface accepts `n1`, `n2`, `n3`, `P` which are all integers. `nx` indicates the number of lattice points along direction `x` i.e. `n1`, `n2` or `n3`. `P` indicates the number of PEs available.

#### Current problem formulation

Since the domain is a cuboid, I'm looking for a 3-part-factorization of `P` such that `P = p1 * p2 * p3` and `px` is proportional to `nx`.

#### Limitations of problem formulation

1. 3-part-factorization algorithm needs to be developed.
2. Some sort of metric must be used to choose any one of the many 3-part-factorizations generated. In the example in the image, `n1 = 3, n2 = 5, n3 = 4` and say, `P = 54`, we would have the 3-part-factorizations `(27, 2, 1)`, `(9, 3, 2)`, `(6, 9, 1)` and `(6, 3, 3)`. Which one is here applicable? A simple magnitude-of-difference metric would choose `(6, 3, 3)`. But even this has multiple permutations `(3, 6, 3)` and `(3, 3, 6)`.
3. If the chosen 3-part-factorization has a factor which is greater than the corresponding lattice size (`nx`) then we would have to truncate it, which means some PEs will do no work.
4. If the chosen 3-part-factorization has a factor (perhaps after the truncation mentioned in the above point) which does not divide its corresponding lattice size, we have unequal work-sharing  (although some PEs might be sleeping as seen in the above point).

#### How reader can help

- How can we improve this inelegant algorithm? Could you suggest any improvement to any of the points in 'Limitations of problem formulation'?
- Is there a better and more formalized approach (i.e. problem formulation)?
- Links to papers/websites/articles/books would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest pointing your favourite search engine at *efficient mpi domain decomposition* and variations on that theme.  There is a lot of prior work on this.  I'll just comment on your current strategy - don't ignore the possibility you might spread a problem of size `54` over a `(4,4,4)` set of PEs and leave some of them idle - that would reduce the time to solution compared with a `(6,3,3)` decomposition.

Comment: Oh, and to add to my previous comment - don't get too stuck on decomposing a global lattice of size `N` into equal pieces all of size `n`.  You could decompose a problem of size `54` into `64` pieces and spread them over `(4,4,4)` processing elements.  There are a lot of ways of skinning this cat.

Comment: Yes, I'm also doing a look-up while this question is (hopefully) being answered by others. The problem is that most searches yield very application-specific ideas e.g. FEM-grids, grids for numerical PDE-solvers etc.

Regarding your first tip: yes, that's true and such considerations further increase the complexity of the algorithm. But its an important point nonetheless.
Regarding padding: the presence of zeroes in my domain would actually distort the results (end goal is a 3D-FFT).

Comment: I didn't suggest padding, just underusing the resources on some of the PEs.

Comment: Duly noted. Thanks for the tips sofar.